# MiKTeX 2.9 doesn't find the includegraphics package

Tags: graphics, errors

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 and when I include the package{Includegraphics} to use graphics, doesn't recognize. So I need help.

Answer (score 7):

In order to include graphics in your document you should use

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

in your document preamble (between `\documentclass{<doc class>}` and `\begin{document}`) which allows you to then use

```
\includegraphics{<filename>}
```

Depending on the compiler you are using (`latex`, or `pdflatex`, or `xelatex`) you may be required to only use specific image types (PDF, EPS, PNG, JPG,...). However, there are ways around this. You can also specify option parameters (like image width, height, etc) using

```
\includegraphics[width=4cm,height=3mm]{filename}
```

For more information on the standard usage, as well as package options, see the [`graphicx` package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf).