# MiKTeX graphicx package missing

Tags: graphics, packages, installing, miktex

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 and tryng to install the `graphicx` package.
But it is not available on the package manager:

[image: graphicx]

Could anyone help on this?

I found [MiKTeX 2.9 doesn't find the includegraphics package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32805/miktex-2-9-doesnt-find-the-includegraphics-package), but there is no answer.

Comment: This is bizarre, since [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) should form part of *every* basic LaTeX installation - it's part of the basic "LaTeX tools". What did you install in terms of MiKTeX 2.9? Perhaps try to re-install completely...

Answer (score 1):

In MiKTeX as well as in TeX Live, `graphicx` is contained in `graphics`. Hence, install `graphics` and you should be all set.

This sort of bundling is relatively common with basic packages or if a single author has a lot of packages (e.g. the [`oberdiek` bundle](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/oberdiek)). To see if a package is part of a bundle, go to its CTAN site. E.g. the following is from the [`graphicx` CTAN page](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx):

[image: graphicx on CTAN]