# How to use \includegraphics with package graphics?

Tags: graphics

When using the package `graphics` instead of `graphicx` (which is absent for MikTeX 2.9, given that it should be included in `graphics`) the figure does not show on the pdf.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphics}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{80.0pt}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-80.0pt}
% when using graphicx next line works:
%\chead{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1.jpg}}
\chead{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth][0,0]{fig1.jpg}}

\begin{document}
\title{Title} 
\date{September 2013}
\author{Sergio}
\maketitle

\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lipsum[1-9]
\end{document}
```

Comment: graphicx has been part of every latex distribution since 1994. Why do you say it is absent?

Comment: I'm sorry: MiKTeX always had  `graphicx` in its distribution. It's part of the ‘required’ series of packages.

Comment: If you want to use graphics syntax (I wouldn't recommend it) then `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\includegraphics{fig1.jpg}}`

Comment: I confirm that `graphicx`is not listed in the packages for MiKTeX 2.9 which I reinstalled yesterday. As you can see in CTAN the package `graphics` is part of "latex-graphics - The LaTeX standard graphics bundle" which includes `graphics`, `graphicx` and 5 more packages.

Comment: Off-topic: You need to use `geometry` to get proper support for `a4paper`. Otherwise the layout will not match the paper properly. But then you should not change `\headheight` or `\textheight` directly but use `\geometry{headheight=80pt}`, for example.

Answer (score 4):

`graphicx` has been part of every latex distribution since 1994. Why do you say it is absent? I would recommend that you use this syntax.

If you want to use `graphics` syntax (I wouldn't recommend it) then to scale a figure use:

```
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\includegraphics{fig1.jpg}}
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. Until now the only good result was obtained using `graphicx` (not `graphics`) and `TeXLive`.

Comment: @sbac "doesn't work" isn't very informative. miktex has graphicx (it is a condition of the latex distribution that it be included) so if you really don't have it you have a completely broken installation and should fix that first.

Comment: @sbac apart from the fact that graphicx.sty should be in the same directory as graphics.sty, if you do use graphics then the `\resizebox` version in this answer will work. If you find it does not post a real example (using `example-image` as the file name so we can run it) and post the exact error message that you get. It would also be useful to post the error message you get from `\usepackage{graphicx}`

Comment: if you go to the [MiKTeX repository](http://miktex.org/packages) you would not see `graphicx`. So I think the problem has not to do with my installation. And as I said I have no problem when using `graphicx`with another TeX installation using TeXLive. Please see this [similar problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141894/miktex-graphicx-package-missing).

Comment: @sbac as explained there and as you commented under the question graphics and graphicx are _not_ distributed on their own, they are distributed as part of latex-graphics so that is the unit that you see on ctan and in texlive and miktex package installs, you install latex-graphics (which will be done already) and you have graphicx, graphics, trig, color latex packages. If you do not have graphicx your installation is broken.

Comment: Sorry, I finally understood and now it works fine: I have installed a package called `graphics`but I use `\usepackage{graphicx}`and not `\usepackage{graphics}` as I did before.